# Get information about a file uploaded to S3

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

i have created a lambda function that sends emails whenever a file is uploaded on s3 bucket, but now i want to have all the informations related to that file as the  name, size, date and time of upload, and if it's possible where it comes from.
I have all this infortmation on aws console, but want to have it in the email body.

i am using **serverless framework. v 1.22.0**

here is my code

```
import json
import boto3
import botocore
import logging
import sys
import os
import traceback


from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from pprint import pprint
from time import strftime, gmtime

email_from = '********@*****.com'
email_to = '********@*****.com'
email_subject = 'new event on s3 '
email_body = 'a new file is uploaded'


#setup simple logging for INFO
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def sthree(event, context):
"""Send email whenever a file is uploaded to S3"""
body = {}
status_code = 200
email_body =  str(context)

try:
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    ses = boto3.client('ses')
    ses.send_email(Source = email_from,
                Destination = {'ToAddresses': [email_to,],}, 
                    Message = {'Subject': {'Data': email_subject}, 'Body':{'Text' : {'Data': email_body}}}
         )
except Exception as e:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    status_code = 500
    body["message"] = json.dumps(e)

response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": json.dumps(body)
}

return response
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the event json structure sent by S3 upon object creation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html

You can get the file names, sizes and source ip like this:

```
for record in event['Records']:
    filename = record['s3']['object']['key'];
    filesize = record['s3']['object']['size'];
    source = record['requestParameters']['sourceIPAddress'];
    eventTime = record['eventTime'];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    email_from = 'XXXXXXXXX@XXX.com'
    email_to = 'XXXXXXXXX@XXX.com'
    email_subject = 'new event on s3'
    email_body = "File Name :" + event[u'Records'][0][u's3'][u'object'][u'key'] + "\n" + "File Size :" + str(event[u'Records'][0][u's3'][u'object'][u'size']) + "\n" +  "Upload Time :" + event[u'Records'][0][u'eventTime'] + "\n" + "User Details :" + event[u'Records'][0][u'userIdentity'][u'principalId']
    ses = boto3.client('ses')
    ses.send_email(Source = email_from,
                Destination = {'ToAddresses': [email_to,],}, 
                    Message = {'Subject': {'Data': email_subject}, 'Body':{'Text' : {'Data': email_body}}}
         )
    print("Function execution Completed !!!")
```